# Django, how to validate between 3 tables?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have 3 models.

```
class Thing (model.Models):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 222)
    ...

class UserProfile(model.Models):
    infos

class Rate(models.Model):
    thing = models.ForeignKey(Thing)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    rate = models.IntegerField()
```

How to make validate between? I want one user to have one rating for one thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a user to have one rating for one thing, then you need a unique constraint on the Rate model for a combination of user and thing. You can define this with `unique_together`:

```
class Rate(models.Model):
    thing = models.ForeignKey(Thing)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    rate = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['thing', 'user']
```